# Is there a browser which supports Socks5 with authentication?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, proxy

I have checked IE8, FF 3.5 , Opera 9 none of them have support for proxy authentication for socks5 proxy server.

Can anyone point me to enable socks 5 authentication or any other browser which has automation APIs available and works with sock5 proxy authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to **create a "SOCKS5 adapter"** that would accepts regular SOCKS5 connections on one side, then forwards them onto an authenticated SOCKS5 proxy on the other.

You could run the "adapter" locally and configure it with the allowed incoming connection (localhost) and outgoing authenticated SOCKS5 proxy and username/password.

Because the first proxy is running locally, you would not incur much of a performance hit.  This would work in any agent which supports any proxy format you want to expose to your browser.

Otherwise, this sounds more like a superuser question.

Answer (score 4):

Opera supports socks5 with authentication. To set you password and username for socks open opera:config page in address bar and then open proxy options.

Comment: This is certainly not the case in 2014 on Opera v20+ in windows. In my Opera v23 it just opens the system's (IE's) proxy settings which doesn't support authentication.

Answer (score 2):

The only Browser I have found that supports Socks5a is Maxthon. Specifically Maxthon 3 browser. I use the portable version on a USB drive to bypass my work VPN. It works perfectly.

Comment: I just downloaded Maxthon Browser portable. It just uses Windows proxy setting, no extra configuration.